# How to select the first auto suggestion using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, autosuggest

I am entering the name which is I want to search then it is displayed auto suggestion, but I am not able to select the first option from autosuggestion.

This is eclipse oxygen with TestNG plugin

```
driver.findElement(By.className("searchfilter")).sendKeys("Abilify");// This is working But after that option selection is not working

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".list-group-item:first-child")).click(); // Issue is here
```

Html code:

```html
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-3 tabindex fs-1-1 bg-offwhite" id="indexTab1" href="970-ABILIFY" name="ABILIFY - ARIPIPRAZOLE">ABILIFY - ARIPIPRAZOLE</li>
```

Comment: <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-3 tabindex fs-1-1 bg-offwhite" id="indexTab1" href="970-ABILIFY" name="ABILIFY - ARIPIPRAZOLE">ABILIFY - ARIPIPRAZOLE</li>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Once you invoke `sendKeys()` with the desired text, to select the first auto suggestion you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.className("searchfilter")).sendKeys("Abilify");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("li.list-group-item-action[name='ABILIFY - ARIPIPRAZOLE'][href$='-ABILIFY']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.className("searchfilter")).sendKeys("Abilify");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[contains(@class, 'list-group-item-action') and @name='ABILIFY - ARIPIPRAZOLE'][contains(., 'ABILIFY - ARIPIPRAZOLE')]"))).click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

1- First enter your word in the search box.

2- then wait until the Elements of your search are visible or clickable.

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, milliseconds);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='indexTab1']"))));
```

3- then click on the desired element

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='indexTab1']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, yours is single page application. Most probably its angular js app. These SPAs keeps updating/displaying options in the dropdown based on what you type in the dropdown editbox.

Please try the following code,

driver.findElement(By.className("searchfilter")).sendKeys("Abilify");

driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//li[contains(text(), 'Abilify')]")) . click() ; // Note : Selenium always work on first element if there are mutiple matches.

You can also parameterize your selection value like the following

String temp=" Abilify";
driver.findElement(By.className("searchfilter")).sendKeys(temp);

driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//li[contains(text()," + temp +")]")).click() ;

Regards,
Partha